# Biblatex: problem with defernumbers

Tags: biblatex, numbering

I'm experiencing a (new) problem with Biblatex after switching computers (for information I am still running the same version 12.04 of Ubuntu but might have a newer version of TeX Live). It seems as though the "defernumbers=true" option used when loading the package does not have the same effect as it used to be. Formerly, after running Biber, three LaTeX runs allowed to reset the numbering of references at 1. It does not work any more. Here is a minimal working example

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[francais,british]{babel}     
\usepackage[style=numeric,defernumbers=true,backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{Biblio.bib}

\begin{document}
\begin{refsection}

The Plemelj-Sochocki theorem \cite{Appel}.

\printbibliography
\end{refsection}

\end{document}
```

with the contents of Biblio.bib as follows:

```
@book{
     Appel,
     author="W. Appel",
     title="Mathematics for Physics \& Physicists",
     edition="1",
     publisher="Princeton University Press",
     year="2007"
}
```

After a single post-Biber run of LaTeX, the reference has label 1 (but things are messy for a realistic document, because the defernumbers option needs two such runs). When I perform the necessary second post-Biber run, the label is raised to 2, and gets stuck there forever regardless of the number of reruns. It is clear from tests with more realistic documents that Biblatex keeps the total number of references in memory and, at the second run, starts the numbering from there. A third run used to correct this on my previous computer. Here is the output:

[image]

I hope the issue was stated clearly. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: I can verify that you example behaves in this incorrect way with the latest biblatex.  May be it is a bug.

Comment: I have not seen this issue reported anywhere so your feedback is very valuable. This means the issue is consistent to some degree.

Comment: The problem occurs here as well (`biblatex 2.8a`/`biber 1.8`), so I suggest you raise this issue with the [`biblatex` bug tracker](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and the suggestion. I reported the problem as advised.

Comment: As the issue was closed in the bug tracker ([issue #213](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/213)), you might want to add a link to this question there.

Comment: @plk This is just to make PLK aware of this question and our suspicion that this behaviour is indeed a bug.

Comment: It was indeed closed because they thought I had not gone through StackExchange first. I am now clarifying this with them, and hope it gets reopened.

Comment: Re-opened, looking into it.

Answer (score 2):

This was a bug. It should be fixed in 2.9 dev version on SF if someone could test?

Comment: I did finally manage to install the 2.9 version. Or so it seems, because it does work now. Many thanks for your quick, effective help. I hope it works for others.

Comment: After having had to install a new system I'm running into the exact same problem. I'm using Biber 1.9 and BibLaTeX 2.9a. I tried to install BibLaTeX 3.0 as advised here

http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/182593/weird-numbers-with-defernumbers-and-refsegment/183671#183671

but the .log file still mentions the 2.9a version instead of the 3.0.

Comment: I am now running Biber 1.9 and BibLaTeX 3.0, as advised in the link just above, and the problem persists. Any suggestions very much appreciated. I'm sorry but I have to provisionally unaccept the answer.

Comment: Hmm, can you try biber 2.0 dev version with biblatex 3.0? biber 1.9 isn't compatible with biblatex 3.0.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it doesn't work for me with biblatex 3.0 and biber 2.0 (beta).

Comment: Looking into it.

Comment: I have re-opened bug https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/213 for this. I have also updated the biblatex 3.0 DEV beta on Sourceforge with a fix if you can test it.

Comment: It now works. I'm sure you've tested it before posting but just to confirm what you may have observed yourself: it takes two pdflatex runs after running biber to get the desired result. And the first of those two runs is somewhat cumbersome as I need to keep pressing [Enter]. Indeed pdflatex stops at every new reference it "meets". Anyway, what's important is the result, and for the moment  it's perfect, so once again, many thanks, mate. You've been of great help.

Comment: That two runs after biber is normal - it's necessary as the .aux file has to pass some values to a second run. It's mentioned in the biblatex manual.

Comment: Sure. I just wanted to confirm the behaviour. Maybe you should post an answer which states that the problem's solved in the 3.0 DEV beta version. I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: Let's wait and make sure it's fixed ...