# biblatex: reference both by chapter and at the end of the book

Tags: biblatex, subdividing

I currently print my references after the end of each chapter, using:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,
    bibencoding=utf8,
    refsection=chapter,
    style=numeric, 
    firstinits=true,
    isbn=false,
    doi=true,
    url=false,
    clearlang=true
]{biblatex}
```

and

```
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
```

at the end of each chapter.

I would like to have also a chapter at the end of the book with all cited references. How could I do ?

Comment: Using the `numeric` style that is a very dangerous idea indeed. There will be a [1] in chapter 1 and a [1] in chapter 2, but they might not necessarily be the same work. What is [1] supposed to be in the cumulative bibliography?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We can use `refsegment` instead of `refsection` (read about `refsection` and `refsegment` in [the `biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) §3.6.5 *Bibliography Sections* & §3.6.6 *Bibliography Segments*, pp. 78-79).

Instead of `refsection=chapter` we pass `refsegment=chapter` to `biblatex`, we also issue `defernumbers=true` (you can find out more about `defernumbers` on p. 53 of the [doc](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf)).

We then have to specify the `segment` in the per-chapter bib manually, but this can be automated with `\therefsegment`, so the chapter-bibliographies are

```
\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,heading=subbibliography]
```

The full end-document bib is created by

```
\printbibliography
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[backend=biber,
    bibencoding=utf8,
    refsegment=chapter,
    style=numeric, 
    firstinits=true,
    isbn=false,
    doi=true,
    url=false,
    clearlang=true,
    defernumbers=true,
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Ch 1}
A citation \cite{wilde}.
\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,heading=subbibliography]

\chapter{Ch 2}
And another one \cite{cicero}.
\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,heading=subbibliography]

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: hi. Thanks, this almost works. In my thesis, defernumbers messes up the numerotation. It starts at 57 for some reason... If i remove it, its seems ok. I don't get the documentation for this option.

Comment: @Napseis I used `defernumbers` to get [1] in the first chapter and [2] in the second. Otherwise it would have been [2] in the first and [1] in the second. As far as I understand `defernumbers` makes sure an entry gets a number the first time it is printed in a bibliography. Note that with `refsection` the numbering was local and confined to one `refsection` (i.e. a chapter) while `refsection` applies global numbering.

Comment: hum, I understand the same thing from the doc. And this is desirable, in fact, but not if it starts from some random number. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Napseis I'm only speculating here, but that may be because of the sorting in the bibliography, maybe a `sorting=none` to the global options might help there. But if it works for you without `defernumbers` and you notice no adverse effects, I guess it's not absolutely necessary to investigate further. If you are interested in a solution though (I know, I am), you could ask a new question with a short MWE that shows the issue (maybe not with 57 entries, probably better 3, 4 or so).

Comment: according to here, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163611/biblatex-problem-with-defernumbers
this is a bug. I don't have Texlive 2014 in Fedora 20,so I will wait..