# How to get the option 'globalcitecopy' of bibunits with biblatex?

Tags: biblatex

I've just changed from [**natbib**](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/natbib) + [**bibunits**](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/bibunits) to [**biblatex**](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) and I'd like to get the functionality of the `globalcitecopy` option. As explained in the documentation of **bibunits**:

> Create an entry in the global bibliography for each cite command within a bibunit. Default is to create an entry only for the local bibliography.

I've defined `refsections`with **biblatex**, but when trying to print the global bibliography either with `\printbibliography` or `\bibbysection` I can't get all the references cited in the whole document shown and sorted all together.

After reading the documentation of **biblatex** I suppose I'm skipping something, but I can't guess. How should it be done?

---

As @moewe pointed out, I was mixing concepts. Just using `segments` instead of `sections` solves it.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,titlepage,10pt,twoside,openright]{report}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=ieee-alphabetic,natbib=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{IEEEfull.bib}
\addbibresource{IEEEexample.bib}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

%\begin{refsection}
\begin{refsegment}
 \chapter{Introduction}
 \cite{IEEEexample:articledualmonths}
 \section{First section}
 \cite{IEEEexample:shellCTANpage}

 %\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
 \printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,heading=subbibliography]
%\end{refsection}
\end{refsegment}

\section{Second section}
\cite{IEEEexample:IEEEwebsite}
\nocite{IEEEexample:book_typical,IEEEexample:article_typical}  

\cleardoublepage

\printbibliography[heading=bibliography]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `refsegment` instead of `refsection` (and `\bibbysegment` instead of `\bibbysection`): `refsection` keep all their citations local, so that they cannot be seen from outside that section, while `refsegment` is global. See [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/199345/35864), for example.