# Chapter wise bibiliography section with only cited contents of each chapter

Tags: biblatex, biber

I am looking at printing bibliography at end of each chapter, where only cited contents need to be printed in it. But I am getting all the contents printed at the end of each chapter. I am using

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric,autocite=plain,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{report.bib}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter 1}
Test\cite{1}
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
\chapter{Chapter 2}
Test\cite{2}\cite{3}
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
\end{document}
```

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/202281/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/199336/35864

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Giving

```
\usepackage[backend=biber, refsegment=chapter, defernumbers=true]{biblatex}
\printbibliography[segment=1,heading=subbibliography]
```

Solved the problem

Comment: It might be more convenient to let `biblatex` figure out the segment number automatically: `segment=\the\value{refsegment}`. (This should work in most set-ups, but might go wrong if the bibliography heading initiates a new segment of its own.) If the chapters are more self-contained one could look into using `refsection`s instead of `refsegment`. `refsection`s keep their contents completely separate, which would mean that the numbering would restart at 1 for each chapter.