# Print bibliography mid way through document including only references cited up until that point

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, pdfpages

For a document I'm writing, I'm required to submit a 2 page summary at the very beginning that briefly covers the rest of the large document. This will need to be standalone, such that it'll need a mini-bibliography at the end that will contain a small subset of the main bibliography at the end of the document. The issue is that the `\printbibliography` command will just repeat the entire thing at the start, completely going over my 2 page limit and including ones that aren't cited in the summary. Is there an easy way to overcome this? I've tried created a separate .tex project and then using `\includepdf` on the result, but that than loses it's hyperlinks which irks me!

Comment: Welcome :) // I'm afraid you'll need to provide some code. To shorten the code you may want to use the blindtext-package to obtain the 2 page summary with just a few lines: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/blindtext . Thanks

Comment: Biblatex allows you to show a subset of the bibliography. See refsegment and refsection in the documentation.

Comment: This question may help: [tex.stackexchange.com/questions/199336](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/199336), instead using `refsegment=section` or whatever is your appropriate level